# How to convert list of map list<map<string, object>> to list of value of map map<string,list<string>> using steam api java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of map. The map contains string as key & object as value. Most likely values also string. I want to group by one value so that I will get a set of value as key and another group of unique values as a list. Actually, list of map is couchbase select data.

e.g:

```
 [{"id":"1", "status":"pending"},{"id":"2", "status":"download"},{"id":"3", "status":"pending"},{"id":"4", "status":"pending"}, {"id":"5", "status":"ready"},{"id":"6", "status":"download"}] => {"pending":["1","3","4"], "download":["2","6"], "ready":["5"]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this out. Notice that my values are `Strings` NOT `Objects` as yours. In your case you need to cast it explicitly to `String` like so,

```
s -> (String) s.get("status")
s -> (String) s.get("id")


Map<String, List<String>> idsByStatus = listOfMap.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.get("status"), Collectors.mapping(s -> s.get("id"), Collectors.toList())));
```